# Selenium firefox can not be started

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

Selenium webdriver using firefox

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "c:\\geckodriver-0.24.0-win64.exe");
WebDrier driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost/index.html");
```

The browser is opened, but page can not be loaded.Error:
       Caused by:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:45855/hub/status] to be available after 45002 ms

        Caused by:
        java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line as below.

> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\geckodriver-0.24.0-win64.exe");

Answer (score 0):

To eliminates lot of manual works and incompatibility issues, I would suggest you to go for **WebDriverManager** as it automatically downloads required binary and we do not need to set any path.

It supports browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer.

Please add below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can open firefox writing code in below way

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
FirefoxOptions fOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
fOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(fOptions);
```